# How to save 'inspect element' changed on a per domain basis?

Tags: html, google-chrome

my school website is very poorly designed, and I want a way to be able to make changes and when Chrome detects the school domain, it loads my changed. Saving it as an .html file will not suffice as the page is constantly changing, thanks Stack!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension that only runs on your schools website.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

This will allow you to add custom JavaScript and CSS to the page.

I hope this is still relevant, it's been a while since I made an extension my self.